# JsonObject in Java

Tags: java, json

**Original Question: Resolved**

I'm producing Json from the controller using JsonObject/JsonArray:

```
    JSONObject headers = new JSONObject();
    headers.put("ID", "");
    headers.put("Organization Name", "");
    headers.put("Submission Date", "");
    headers.put("Status", "");

    JSONObject organizationsHJ = new JSONObject();
    organizationsHJ.put("headers", headers);

    array.add(organizationsHJ );
```

This produces JSON as: 
`"headers":{"Status":"","Submission Date":"","Organization Name":"","ID":""}`

Instead I need to get the output as:

```
"headers":[  "ID",  "Organization Name",  "Submission Date",  "Status"  ]
```

Is that possible? Please advise. Please note I can have the JSON as a javascript variable as well if that's easier?

**EDIT:**

I need one more simple change in the JSON output. Here is my code:

```
JSONObject notifications = new JSONObject();
notifications.put("id", "1");
notifications.put("description", "Notification 1");
notifications.put("createdTimestamp", "2015-05-12T18:15:28.237Z");
notifications.put("startTimestamp", "2015-05-25T18:30:28.237Z");
notifications.put("endTimestamp", "2015-06-13T12:30:30.237Z");
notifications.put("active", "true");
```

This generates JSON output as:

```
{"data":{"id":"1","createdTimestamp":"2015-05-12T18:15:28.237Z","description":"Notification 1","startTimestamp":"2015-05-25T18:30:28.237Z","active":"true","createdId":"251","endTimestamp":"2015-06-13T12:30:30.237Z"}}
```

Instead I want it to generate as:

```
{"data":["id":"1","createdTimestamp":"2015-05-12T18:15:28.237Z","description":"Notification 1","startTimestamp":"2015-05-25T18:30:28.237Z","active":"true","createdId":"251","endTimestamp":"2015-06-13T12:30:30.237Z"]}
```

Comment: That's an array, not an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`headers` should be a [`JSONArray`](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples#Example_2-1_-_Encode_a_JSON_array), not `JSONObject`. An object is a set of name-to-value mappings, an array is a linear collection.

```
JSONArray headers = new JSONObject();
headers.add("ID");
headers.add("Organization Name");
headers.add("Submission Date");
headers.add("Status");

JSONObject organizationsHJ = new JSONObject();
organizationsHJ.put("headers", headers);

array.add(organizationsHJ );
```

Comment: This is not working. I'm using org.json.simple.JSONArray

Comment: Try using `.add` instead of `.put`. That's what the examples at the `JSON.somple` website use.

Comment: Awesome. This works. I have one more similar issue, but woud put rather put it here instead of creating a new thread. Please see my edit.

Comment: What you want is not possible. `key:value` pairs can only be in objects, not in arrays. `{ }` is used around objects, `[ ]` is around arrays.

Comment: Ok thanks. The issue is in Javascript. It tries to loop the "data" using data.length and the error is length is undefined...Any other workaround?

Comment: In other words, I can even create/generate the json in javascript directly too? Is that possible?

Comment: That's not how you loop over objects in Javascript. You use `for (key in object) { do something with object[key] }`.

Comment: I added a js var that works for now. Still have a few more issues to resolve. Thanks so much and I marked your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

organizationsHJ.put("headers", headers.keySet());

Comment: For some weird reason, my unit test works fine. But the headers are empty when run on the actual application when the json is sent from server to client???? Not sure why!